# Understanding jQuery plugin development pattern

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

According to the [jQuery plugin authoring guidelines](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), a basic plugin structure would look like this:

```
(function($){

  $.fn.myPlugin = function( options ) {  

    return this.each(function() {

      // Do something...

    });
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Yet I've seen the following pattern in several jQuery plugins I've inspected:

```
(function($){
        $.extend($.fn, {
            myPlugin: function( options ) {

                $(this).each( function() {
                    // Do something
                });
        },
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Can someone explain the second approach- What is `$.extend(...` and the object-notation all about?

Thanks-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two are basically accomplishing the same task, but in a slightly different manner.

`$.fn.myPlugin = …` is directly assigning the function to the place you want it in the jQuery namespace.

`$.extend($.fn, {myPlugin:…` is **extending** the `$.fn` object with the object specified as the second parameter. In this case, the object simply contains a single property, `myPlugin`, which is the function to add.

You can use either structure, although I personally find the first a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The [`$.extend` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is used to:

> Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

So this:

```
$.extend($.fn, { ... });
```

Is just merging the contents of the object literal into `$.fn`. Using `$.extend` like this just really just another way of doing the normal/standard assignment:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = ...
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation- Michael beat you by a hair

Comment: @Yarin: That's cool, I mostly wanted to get the link to the official `$.extend` docs through. And yes, the direct assignment is a lot cleaner (IMHO, YMMV, etc).